# anr broadcast of intent. What is my mistake?

Tags: java, android

anr broadcast of intent { act=android.provider.Telefony.SMS_RECEIVED cmp=com.site/.SmsReceived {has extras}} in}}

What is my mistake?

Shows the error when it comes to SMS. BroadcastReceiver: connects to sqllite and search number is the same sender SMS.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail about your goals and what problem you're facing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your onReceive() method in BroadcastReceiver works longer than 10s, while it must finish earlier.

Comment: So, means necessary processing onReceive make in a child thread?

Comment: Common way to do that is use BR to start Service or Activity (but remember about 5s limit for Activity.onCreate()). BR lifecycle should finish when onReceive() finishes.